# Downloading incorrect xlsx file

Tags: c#, html, iis, .net-core

I used this tag for users to download files correctly.

`<a href="upload/@newmodel.AttachFile" target="_blank" ><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`

the result is :

```
<a href="upload/Files/fa39fa29-85b6-4978-854f-ca156151f777/PART 041.mp4" target="_blank" download="download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<a href="upload/Files/122d3f13-767f-4405-94c5-e4166f0981bb/Hlp-Lifeplus-Enteghal-V001-990824-01.pdf" target="_blank" download="download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<a href="upload/Files/251823aa-1ece-4b21-afae-3cb4439e3828/services990730ref01.xlsx" target="_blank" download="download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

it works correctly for downloading these files
, Except files with extension xlsx, it couldn't download it correctly and it
changes the downloaded file name and after downloading could not open the file.

[image]

furthermore in IE it works but not it doesn't work in Firefox and chrome browsers.

Comment: Seems you should introduce XSLX somewhere in you allowed MIME types

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with C#, XLSX or .NET Core. There's no relevant code in the question, just HTML

Comment: BTW the filename you *explicitly* propose for that file is `download`. You specifically tell all browsers to save your files as `download`. For some reason, Chrome and Firefox *ignore what you told them*. The surprising behavior is that any file was saved with the correct extension, not that one file was saved with the filename you specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the tags are wrong but for some reason only the Excel file is treated as expected. `download` should either be empty or contain the desired file name. Perhaps IIS is explicitly specifying a `Content-Disposition` header for configured media types that overcomes the error?

To fix the problem specify the desired file name in the `download` tag, eg :

```
<a href="upload/Files/fa39fa29-85b6-4978-854f-ca156151f777/PART 041.mp4" 
   target="_blank" download="PART 041.mp4">
...</a>
<a href="upload/Files/251823aa-1ece-4b21-afae-3cb4439e3828/services990730ref01.xlsx" 
   target="_blank" download="services990730ref01.xlsx">
...</a>
```

From [Mozilla Developer Network's tag reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (ie Firefox's docs):

> download
> Prompts the user to save the linked URL instead of navigating to it. Can be used with or without a value:
>
> - Without a value, the browser will suggest a filename/extension, generated from various sources:
>
> > - The Content-Disposition HTTP header
> > - The final segment in the URL path
> > - The media type (from the (Content-Type header, the start of a data: URL, or Blob.type for a blob: URL)
>
> - Defining a value suggests it as the filename. / and \ characters are converted to underscores (_). Filesystems may forbid other characters in filenames, so browsers will adjust the suggested name if necessary.

And

> Note: if the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behaviour may differ:

> -If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.

This means that somehow, a `Content-Disposition` header is specified for the PDF and MP4 files that overrides the `download` attribute. You can check this either through the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools or through a debugging proxy like Fiddler

Comment: I did so ,it works fine in mozila but in chrome,instead of downloading ,it opens evrythings